# Reading from a file in java

Tags: java, file, bufferedreader

Ok so I use this code to read from files but it returns me the filename.

```
public void read(String file){
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(file);
    System.out.println(sc.nextInt());
    sc.close();
}
```

And I want to know how can I check to see if the file is unexistent before reading from it.

Comment: Read the javadoc of classes you use _before_ you use them.

Comment: Use a try/catch block with `FileNotFoundException`.

Comment: If you want to read content of file use `new Scanner(new File("pathToFile"))`. If you use `new Scanner("some String")` it will just read content of passed String.

Answer (score 0):

```
File file = new File("path of file here...");

BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
String line;
while((line=in.readLine())!=null){
System.out.println(line);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this may be helpful:

```
 FileInputStream stream = new FileInputStream("src/transactions.txt");
 fileIn = new Scanner(stream);
```

Answer (score 0):

A scanner can take many kinds of input strings/streams/etc.  I would seriously consider reading the javadocs early and often as suggested by Sotirios Delimanolis.

```
public void read (String filename) {
    try {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File(filename));    
        System.out.println(sc.nextInt());
        sc.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException) {
        //handle your error here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `file.exists()` method to check if a file is valid.

Answer (score 0):

Code Snippet to help:

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("filepath"));
        try {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = br.readLine();

            while (line != null) {
                sb.append(line);
                sb.append(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
                line = br.readLine();
            }
            everything = sb.toString();
            System.out.println(everything);
        } finally {
            br.close();
        }
```